# Postgres from Python: can I fetch N rows per time in a loop?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have the following case:

```
conn=ps.connect("dbname='xxxx' user='xxxx' password='xxxx'")
crs = conn.cursor()
statement= """ SELECT *FROM aaaa; 
""" 
crs.execute(statement)
# get the name of the cars
var = crs.fetchall()
```

But given the large size of the table, Ubuntu kills the process because of memory issues.

How can I fetch `N` rows per time in a loop? For instance something like this:

```
N=1000
for i in range(0,10):
   var = crs.fetchmany(0:N)
   N+=1000
```

Answer (score 2):

fetchmany returns up to n next rows and None when there are none left.

```
rows = crs.fetchmany(1000)
while(rows):
    # do stuff
    rows = crs.fetchmany(1000)
else:
    # done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html):

```
cur.fetchmany(2)
```

the cursor class will allow you to fetchone or fetchmany.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way:

```
query = """SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxxxx;
"""
crs.execute(query)
N = crs.fetchall()
N = N[0][0]
for i in range(0,N):
    if n1 == N: continue
    n1 = n + 1000
    print n,n1
    if n1 > N:
        n1 == N
    statement = """ SELECT * FROM xxxxx limit %d offset %d;
    """%(n1,n)
    crs.execute(statement)
    var  = crs.fetchall()
```

Comment: I tried to give an answer. Thanks for your comments.